Mr Victor Nunes
Hi all, do anyone know what happened with the website Sonalanastaker.com, is possible to be a fraud ?
i’m trying to log in from UK but show a message sayng the safari couldn’t find the web page…

probably a scam. Don't sign anything from it and if you did, discard that wallet and create a new one.
